# Selenium cannot click in webpage using CSS_SELECTOR

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I want to click this button in facebook for show all comment
[image]

I use this code to login and open url

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

# set options as you wish
option = Options()
option.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
option.add_argument("start-maximized")
option.add_argument("--disable-extensions")


EMAIL = "myemail"
PASSWORD = "mypassword"
    
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="./chromedriver", options=option)
browser.get("http://facebook.com")
browser.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 30)
email_field = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME, 'email')))
email_field.send_keys(EMAIL)
pass_field = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME, 'pass')))
pass_field.send_keys(PASSWORD)
pass_field.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

time.sleep(5)

browser.get('https://www.facebook.com/NetflixTH/photos/a.292183707902294/1709518956168755/') # once logged in, free to open up any target page

time.sleep(5)

browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'i[class="x1b0d499 x1d69dk1"]').click();
```

When I run this code it show error like this. How to fix it?

```
ElementClickInterceptedException: element click intercepted: Element <i data-visualcompletion="css-img" class="x1b0d499 x1d69dk1" style="background-image: url(&quot;https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v3/yq/r/uo1Qvq4bB06.png&quot;); background-position: 0px -536px; background-size: 26px 926px; width: 16px; height: 16px; background-repeat: no-repeat; display: inline-block;"></i> is not clickable at point (1180, 360). Other element would receive the click: <div class="x1uvtmcs x4k7w5x x1h91t0o x1beo9mf xaigb6o x12ejxvf x3igimt xarpa2k xedcshv x1lytzrv x1t2pt76 x7ja8zs x1n2onr6 x1qrby5j x1jfb8zj" tabindex="-1">...</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

An `ElementClickInterceptedException` occurs whenever the element you're trying to click isn't actually visible to the browser, that is, there's something over it. For example, if a modal opens, then you won't be able to click any of the buttons that are behind the modal.

The easiest way to fix this is to use JavaScript to click the button instead. While you might not be able to see the element, you can still run its the JavaScript `Element.click()` method. Just replace this line:

```
browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'i[class="x1b0d499 x1d69dk1"]').click();
```

with this:

```
el = browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'i.x1b0d499.x1d69dk1"]')
browser.execute_script('arguments[0].click();', el)
```